# Grouping nested table rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

What would be the best way of grouping table rows in an HTML table? Some of the groupings are supposed to be nested, so using `<tbody>` is not an ideal solution (they are not supposed to be nested).

My data has the following format:

```
Level 1
Level 1
    Level 2
    Level 2
        Level 3
            Level 4
        Level 3
        Level 3
    Level 2
Level 1
    Level 2
        Level 3
            Level 4
            Level 4
        Level 3
    Level 2
        Level 3
```

What I am trying to achieve:

- sensible document structure that's easy to read
- so far I achieved the 'easy to read' part with css for different levels
- some of the nested levels may be required to be collapsible, so a grouping would (?) make things easier. It would have to work such that nested level immediately following any particular higher level would collapse via some mechanism (clicking, most likely). Not sure how much sense this collapsing makes but it may be one of the requirements.

The table is generated in JavaScript (from a JSON object that has a nested structure), so I can do all sorts of magic to it. The data represents a financial balance sheets, and sometimes you may want do display/hide more detailed information on any particular data row, hence the nesting.

Comment: Have you seen bootstrap [collapsible](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#collapse)

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work. The data represents a balance sheet, so data has to be in a table format

Comment: The question describes an abstract structure of “levels”. There is nothing table-like in it. The question is both too vague and too broad (asking people to design markup structure for something defined very loosely).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no good way of doing this in HTML. I would use JQuery Datatable.

http://jquery-datatables-row-grouping.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/customGroupOrdering.html

Try looking at that example

Answer (score 1):

I came to the same problem to solve, here's my solution, I hope it'll help..

The thing for me was to add a few attributes (`rowname, parent, state`) to each row of the table. State attribute can be either **"opened"**, **"collapsed"** or **"leaf"**. Then two javascript functions will do the magic, see the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krpec/1r7p14qb/).

Answer (score 0):

You can give try to Vertical menus which will have levels too and collapsible panels too. there are so many templates available . just an idea .